# Cause of slowdowns when using alternate methods of loading a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv, dictionary

I am routinely loading large (~8gb) .csv files as a dataframe for my script. Due to issues with functions provided by pandas not fitting my needs, I decided to partition this large dataframe into a dictionary. Each day of data inside of the dataframe is stored as a separate, smaller dataframe accessible by the date as a key for the dictionary. (This allowed for very fast lookup times in the subsequent simulation process, each loop of which covers every single date.)

Because searching over the large dataframe for all rows that matched each successive date was time consuming, I rewrote the process to store chunks of the .csv in a list along with the minimum and maximum date in that chunk. Then I loaded it into the dictionary as before, and if part of the data was split across multiple chunks, I concatenated the two dataframes together.

This worked without any immediately noticeable flaws; the process of breaking the dataframe into the dictionary went from ~40 minutes to about fifteen seconds and the rest of the script executed without errors. However, I noticed that the average time to process a portion of the data went up to ~3.5 seconds per cycle compared to my prior benchmark of ~2.5 seconds.

This is not the first time I've noticed something like this. A few months ago, for faster testing and debugging purposes, I created a smaller .csv file via pandas that only contained the most recent two years of data, which translated to about an ~800mb file and much faster loading time. However, the time to process a portion of that data went up to ~20 seconds from the prior benchmark of ~12 seconds. I could not find any meaningful difference between the two tables; they had the same column types and the same number of columns. Nonetheless, processing the smaller table consistently led to slower simulation compared to simply loading the original, complete .csv as a dataframe. I especially note this because that slowdown predated the introduction of splitting the dataframe into daily tables inside of a dictionary.

To summarize my current process:

1. Load in the .csv (in chunks of 20000 lines)
2. Concatenate the chunks into a single dataframe
3. Breakout each day of data from the dataframe into a dictionary
4. Simulate

The new process:

1. Load in the .csv (in chunks of 20000 lines)
2. Breakout each day of data from all chunks whose max and minimum date straddle or match the specified date into a dictionary
3. Simulate

The breakout stage of the new process is much faster, but simulation is much slower.

I'm still fairly new to pandas, so this problem is perplexing to me. It seems as if the original .csv is "pure," and further handling of a dataframe created from it dilutes this purity and slows my simulation process.
In the first case, I loaded the .csv, concatenated its chunks into a dataframe, performed a .loc call to get a subset of rows from the dataframe, saved the result as a separate .csv, and loaded that in place of the original .csv.
In the second case, I have loaded the .csv without concatenating its chunks, peformed a .loc call to get a subset of rows from those specific chunks, and concatenated the results in the results of a dictionary.

One thing I did notice this time, however, was that my new process consistently results in a 10.5 GB dictionary, while the older process results in a 12.2 GB dictionary. So there is *something* about the new process that resulted in a considerably smaller table that processes slower than the benchmark.

The old method:

```py
chunkList = [chunk for chunk in pandas.read_csv(f'{SOURCE}_candles.csv', chunksize=20000, low_memory=False)]
candles = pandas.concat(chunkList)
del chunkList

print("Got candles")

# Data type insurance...

candles['tm_uuid'] = candles['tm_uuid'].astype("string")
candles['ticker'] = candles['ticker'].astype("string")
candles['price_date'] = pandas.to_datetime(candles['price_date']).dt.date

# Specify the start date; don't want to waste time looking at days we don't care about

candles = candles.loc[(candles['price_date'] >= simul_date), :]

# Now get the active dates to use as keys for the dictionary.

activeDates = candles[CandleColumn.PRICE_DATE.value].unique().tolist()

print("Got active dates")

timerTest = time.time()
candlesDict = {}

# Now breakout into the dictionary

for date in activeDates:
    candlesDict[date] = candles.loc[(candles[CandleColumn.PRICE_DATE.value] == date), :]
    candlesDict[date].set_index(CandleColumn.TM_UUID.value, drop=False, inplace=True)
    print(f"Finished {date}")

print(f"Done in {time.time() - timerTest}")
print(f"Candles dictionary uses {sum([sys.getsizeof(candlesDict[date]) for date in activeDates]) / 1024}kb")

# We no longer need the candles table, so clear it from memory!
del candles
```

And the new method:

```py
candles = [chunk for chunk in pandas.read_csv(f'{SOURCE}_candles.csv', chunksize=20000, low_memory=False)]

# Data type insurance...

for table in candles:
    table['tm_uuid'] = table['tm_uuid'].astype("string")
    table['ticker'] = table['ticker'].astype("string")
    table['price_date'] = pandas.to_datetime(table['price_date']).dt.date

# Specify the start date; don't want to waste time looking at days we don't care about

# todo this method is bad practice, create new list and copy. Maybe inplace drop of specified rows?
# Removing this does not improve processing speed...
for index, table in enumerate(candles):
    candles[index] = table.loc[(table['price_date'] >= simul_date), :]

# Now get the active dates to use as keys for the dictionary.

activeDatesUnflattened = [table[CandleColumn.PRICE_DATE.value].unique().tolist() for table in candles]
# Not much point to the .unique() call anymore eh?
activeDates = list(set(list(chain.from_iterable(activeDatesUnflattened))))
activeDates.sort()
del activeDatesUnflattened

timerTest = time.time()
candlesDict = {}
tableDates = []

# Capture the min and max dates for each table in the list

for table in candles:
    tableDates.append((table[CandleColumn.PRICE_DATE.value].min(), table[CandleColumn.PRICE_DATE.value].max()))

# Now breakout into the dictionary

for date in activeDates:
    for index, table in enumerate(candles):
        if date >= tableDates[index][0] and date <= tableDates[index][1]:
            # The date is within the bounds of the table
            if date in candlesDict.keys():
                # If there is a table there, we need to concat the two and make sure the index
                candlesDict[date] = pandas.concat([(table.loc[(table[CandleColumn.PRICE_DATE.value] == date), :]).set_index(CandleColumn.TM_UUID.value, drop=False, inplace=True), candlesDict[date]])
                # todo Faster way to preserve index?
            else:
                candlesDict[date] = table.loc[(table[CandleColumn.PRICE_DATE.value] == date), :]
                candlesDict[date].set_index(CandleColumn.TM_UUID.value, drop=False, inplace=True)
        else:
            continue
    print(f"Finished {date}")

print(f"Done in {time.time() - timerTest}")
print(f"Candles dictionary uses {sum([sys.getsizeof(candlesDict[date]) for date in activeDates]) / 1024}kb")

# We no longer need the candles table, so clear it from memory!
del candles
```

Comment: If you have that big files, CSV is probably not the ideal format. Maybe [parquet](https://www.databricks.com/glossary/what-is-parquet)?

Comment: @mozway Thanks, I'll check it out. I still want to know what's going on in my situation though, if only for the sake of understanding.